# How do I prevent the QPushButton.clicked from the widget from executing when I'm in MainWindow pyqt5?

Tags: pyqt5

I set the `printInWidget` clicked method for the `btnprint` button in widget1. But I want to replace that command in MainWindow with command `printInMain` by code: `self.wid.btnprint.clicked.connect(self.printInMain)`. I don't know why it does both commands in MainWindow. Please help me make the command `printInWidget` not execute when running MainWidow.
Sorry everyone (English is not my native language and I only approached `pyqt5` for a few months by teaching myself).

[image]

when I click button "printText"
[image]

my code:
mainwindow.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QGridLayout, QVBoxLayout, QFileDialog,QHBoxLayout,QSpacerItem,QSizePolicy
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore

import sys
from widget1 import *


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi("MainWindow.ui", self)
        self.wid = widget1()
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.wid)
        self.wid.btnprint.clicked.connect(self.printInMain)
    # I want to override method of button printText
    def printInMain(self):
        self.wid.labelB.setText('New text (method in Main)')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = UI()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

widget1.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import uic


class widget1(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('widget1.ui',self)
        self.btnprint.clicked.connect(self.printInwidget)

    def printInwidget(self):
        self.labelA.setText('Hello World (Method in Widget)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main = QMainWindow()
    widget = widget1()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The code for `widget1` cannot work due to missing dependencies. Also missing UI file. Please provide full code.

Comment: @rbaleksandar the provided code, while not fully reproducible due to the missing ui, is clearly enough to understand the question and answer (as you actually did, as a matter of fact, and you could even have used the provided code as basis for the explanation). Also, what missing dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disconnect. If you want to use the initial behaviour again you need to connect the signal to the slot again. I would suggest creating a `reconnect()` function that will do that for you if you decide to do the whole thing many times.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586643/pyqt-widget-connect-and-disconnect) is an example.

More info can be found in the [official `QObject` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html) (look for `bool QObject::disconnect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const QObject *receiver, const char *method)`).

Also try to provide full code or at least a minimal working example. What you have posted right now cannot work due to missing dependencies and a UI file.