# Will the following code disconnect all incoming or outgoing PyQt signals?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, signals-slots, slot

In my PyQt5 (Python 3.8) application, many `QWidget()`s get created and destroyed dynamically. Although I pay close attention to the destruction of every `QWidget()` - something must have slipped. Each cycle, the RAM consumption goes up.

### 1. The one-liner to disconnect them all

I've read the following blogpost about disconnecting `pyqtSignal()`s:
https://www.sep.com/blog/prevent-signal-slot-memory-leaks-in-python/

At the bottom, the blogpost mentions the following one-liner to disconnect all `pyqtSignal()`s to/from (?) a `QObject()`:

```py
for x in filter(lambda y: type(y) == pyqtBoundSignal and 0 < element.receivers(y), map(lambda z: getattr(element, z), dir(element))): x.disconnect()
```

Supposing that `element` represents a `QObject()` instance, I wonder if this one-liner will actually destroy all *incoming* or *outgoing* signals?

I've tried to rewrite this one-liner in an actual function:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def disconnect_signals_connected_to_qobject(qobj:QObject) -> None:
    '''
    Disconnect all signals that are connected to a slot in the given 'qobj'.
    '''
    for x in filter(
            lambda y: type(y) == pyqtBoundSignal and 0 < qobj.receivers(y),
            map(
                lambda z: getattr(qobj, z),
                dir(qobj)
            )
    ):
        x.disconnect()
    return
```

If the code destroys all *incoming* signals, then the chosen name `disconnect_signals_connected_to_qobject()` is correct. Otherwise, I should rename the function into `disconnect_signals_emitted_from_qobject()`. What's the correct name?

### 2. Does this really disconnect *all* pyqtSignals?

I still have this nagging feeling that the code will "forget" a few disconnections. Some time ago, I found the following code snippet that claims to disconnect a signal *completely*:

```py
def discon_sig(signal):
    '''
    Disconnect only breaks one connection at a time,
    so loop to be safe.
    '''
    while True:
        try:
            signal.disconnect()
        except TypeError:
            break
    return
```

It looks like the one-liner from the blog post forgot the fact that a `signal.disconnect()` invocation only disconnects one connection at a time. So perhaps, I should rewrite my function like this:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

def disconnect_signals_connected_to_qobject(qobj:QObject) -> None:
    '''
    Disconnect all signals that are connected to a slot in the given 'qobj'.
    '''
    # Define inner function for a complete signal
    # disconnection
    def discon_sig(signal):
        while True:
            try:
                signal.disconnect()
            except TypeError:
                break
        return

    # Loop to find all signals that need
    # disconnection
    for x in filter(
            lambda y: type(y) == pyqtBoundSignal and 0 < qobj.receivers(y),
            map(
                lambda z: getattr(qobj, z),
                dir(qobj)
            )
    ):
        discon_sig(x)
    return
```

### 3. Is disconnecting enough?

I'm getting even more worried after reading this mail thread between a user and the PyQt creator Phil Thompson:

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2019-September/042180.html

Long story short - the user claims that disconnecting `pyqtSignal()`s is not enough to prevent memory leaks. According to his experiments, it's vital that *each* `pyqtSignal()` was bound to a decorated slot. Throw in a few undecorated slot, and eternal doom awaits thee:

> **Kevin <sub>(the 'user' writing to Phil Thompson)</sub>**
>
> My assumption was that the memory usage from the signal connections wouldn't "build up" (i.e. that memory usage would be independent of the number of `SignalObject()`s instantiated), which seems to be what happens with the `@pyqtSlot()` decorated version.  In `create_slot_objects()`, each `SlotObject()` is instantiated, which connects the signals, and then should be immediately garbage collected, which should disconnect the signals.  In the version of the script without the `@pyqtSlot()` decorators, the number reported for *"Memory after slot objects creation"* is proportional to the number of `SlotObject()` instances created, which is why I'd assumed memory had leaked, but I could certainly be thinking through things wrong.

I couldn't find a clear answer from Phil, so I'm now officially paranoid about each and every `pyqtSignal()` that lives in my application.

### 4. Is disconnecting *all* signals actually good?

I just performed a test on my application. When browsing through my `QGridLayout()`'s widgets (in reversed order), I do the following to clean them up:

```py
disconnect_signals_connected_to_qobject(widg)
widg.setParent(None)
widg.deleteLater()
sip.delete(widg)
```

Despite doing this, I had a memory leak of almost `100 MB` per cycle - with one cycle being the filling of my table with 1000 rows and emptying the table again.

Now I omit the `pyqtSignal` disconnection:

```py
widg.setParent(None)
widg.deleteLater()
sip.delete(widg)
```

The memory leak dropped to around `20~25 MB` per cycle. How is this possible? Maybe the indiscriminate disconnection of *all* `pyqtSignal`s is hindering a proper cleanup of the `QWidget()`s involved? Maybe one has to carefully decide what `pyqtSignal` to keep and which ones to disconnect? Does this mean that the blogpost cited at the start of this question (see https://www.sep.com/blog/prevent-signal-slot-memory-leaks-in-python/) is actually giving bad advice?

Comment: "a signal.disconnect() invocation only disconnects one connection at a time." AFAIK (as the documentation also says), `signal.disconnect([slot])` "If [slot] is omitted then the signal is disconnected from everything it is connected to.". Can you provide a MRE?

Comment: The first example shown in section 2 is a garbled re-write of code designed for a different purpose. It seems to be based on a misinterpretation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589403/984421), which does not make the claims you allude to. In fact, it clearly states that the while-loop is needed for safely disconnecting a ***specific handler*** which has been connected to the same signal multiple times. However, in the interests of clarity, I have now amended the answer slightly to avoid any further doubt.

Comment: I would also like to second the request by musicamante for an MRE. There are many different reasons why a memory leak may occur, so without a concrete test case, an unequivocal answer isn't really possible.

Comment: Hi @musicamante and @ekhumoro, I would like to give a MRE, but it's a large application and very difficult to extract an MRE from it. However, I just got a notice from a colleague that the memory leak is fixed. Applying a `QStyle()` on a menu - something that we used to do on certain customized `QWidget()`s - seemed to hinder proper garbage collection. We don't know why exactly - maybe that's food for more research or another question.
Thanks @ekhumoro for clarifying https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586643/pyqt-widget-connect-and-disconnect/21589403#21589403